# Do I still need ascii/entity characters in my HTML when supporting modern browsers?

Tags: html, utf-8

I was wondering when I use UTF-8 as a charset in my HTML if I still need to use `&euml;` instead of `ë` for example when dealing with modern browsers(Let's say IE11+)

Can it affect screenreaders for example?

Comment: BTW, what you're talking about aren't "ASCII characters" but HTML entities. Yes, you still need "ASCII characters" (all the characters that appear in the ASCII charset, even if you encode them in some other encoding like UTF-8, where they're identical to ASCII anyway).

Comment: Is your HTML 4.01 or 5 or ?. [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#charset) says, "Authors should use UTF-8" for the document encoding. That would imply that character references are not needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're saving your HTML as proper UTF-8, and you're declaring that correctly in the HTML and HTTP headers, then there's no need to use HTML entities in place of actual characters.

(As long as your HTML stays valid; i.e. you still need `&lt;` if you want to write the `<` character, because that has a special meaning in HTML)